# How to keep password in another table in laravel and use with default auth of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to keep password in other table rather than the default table 'User' in laravel. The default login of laravel search for 'password' in the 'user' table. I want to just change the table it searches keeping other as default.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48339615/1531971

Comment: The answer doesn't work as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339615/laravel-authentication-username-and-password-in-different-tables)

Comment: @JonStirling to know how auth in laravel works and Normalization

Comment: To see how Laravel works, you can read the code. It's also unclear how taking the password out of the user table would be normalising it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

ON the **User** model you can specify your own table with your usernames and passwords.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{

    protected $table = 'customUsersTable';
....
```

Comment: I think OP only wants the password field in a different table, "_keeping other as default_"

Comment: at beginning I think he only wanted to store the passwords on a different table, an then if he is going to have the passwords on a different table, he also need an id or username to relate the 2 different tables, that's why I posted I think at the end of the day he is going to use another table.. just my thinking.

Comment: This changes the whole table. I just want password on other table. Even after hasOne relation and belongsTo realtion between the model, login doesnt search in other table. I want login to check password in password table.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to change will be in your `Config/auth.php` file, you will have a Authentication Default array of..

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

The 'guard' points to the 'guards' array slightly further down in that file. That looks like this...

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

The provider 'users' points to a provider slightly further down in that file again. That looks like this...

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\SecurityUser::class,
        ],
    ],
```

The 'model' is the table that the guard is on, so just change the table to the one you want!

I hope this helped and that I understood your question correctly :D

Comment: this only changes the model of the auth.