# Laravel: Auth::attempt when login and password in different tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I have a user table

```
userId
name
```

And password table

```
pwd_rec_id
userId
pwd_sHash
```

In User model

```
    public function userpwd() {
        return $this->hasOne(UsersPassword::class, 'userId', 'userId' );
    }

    public function getPasswordAttribute() {
        return $this->userpwd?->getAttribute('pwd_sHash');
    }

    protected $appends = [
        'password'
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->attributes['password']; // <<<< line xx
    }
```

When I try to

```
 Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

> WARNING  Undefined array key "password" in app\Models\User.php on line xx.

> DEPRECATED  password_get_info(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($hash) of type string is deprecated in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher.php on line 15.

> RuntimeException  This password does not use the Bcrypt algorithm.

what a wrong with it?

When use User::find(6) result is

```
    = App\Models\User {#5278
        userId: 6,
        name: "Taylor",
        +password: "$2y$12$sbMA3gNT/x00xcxY0IQW5OD3hWlgH4iw1ZUi6WRDc42ylhgxNc886",
```

I've try to rename

`return $this->attributes['password'];`

to

`return $this->attributes['pwd_sHash'];`

and still getting an error above.

Comment: why two tables for that?

Comment: Laravel and its Auth class expects the password to be in the same table as the User table. Why are you attempting to change the default table structure?

Comment: I really need it. Cannot be changet

Comment: @aynber how it can be changet in laravel?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never heard of anyone changing that structure and use Laravel Auth.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339615/laravel-authentication-username-and-password-in-different-tables

Comment: i think you need to use a custom guard and a custom provider in laravel for that by defining it in config/auth.php

Comment: then you can this Auth::guard('custom_guard')->attempt($credentials)

Comment: your password isn't an attribute, it is an accessor ... it isn't in the `$attributes` array ... also `getAuthPassword` by default returns `$this->password`

Comment: @Danny why did you add this `getAuthPassword` method? What happens without it?